# Projector calibration?

Tags: ros, calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there standard tools for projector calibration in ROS or OpenCV?  I've seen some scattered projects on the web but it would be great to have more built-in functionality for the instance of a projector mounted on a robot.

I think the standard approach is to have a in-scene chessboard to determine the position of the surface that the projector then projects a chessboard onto which determines the intrinsic/extrinsic projector parameters- it seems like cv::calibrateCamera could almost accomplish this but some steps are missing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9622/projector-calibration?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2011-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe this exists.  I suggest you file a feature request on the [opencv trac](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/newticket?component=please%20specify&type=enhancement&priority=minor)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check vpclib:

free-dee.org/vpc

---

Originally posted by [urbeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/3940/urbeller/) with karma: 1 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1